# .NET edit specific XML nodes after finding them with XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml

Certain nodes in an XML file need to be edited.

I collected them with an XmlTextReader. If I come across a Remark node, I skip to the next node. If I come across the other specified nodes and they don't start with a certain pattern, I put them in a collection.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
string key = "";
string value = "";
reader = new XmlTextReader(file);

switch (reader.NodeType)
{
    case XmlNodeType.Element:
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            case "Remark":
                reader.Skip();
                break;
            case "DataTableColumn":
            case "Label":
            case "Button":
            case "PopupPanel":
                while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "ID":
                            key = reader.Value;
                            break;
                        case "Header":
                        case "Caption":
                            value = reader.Value;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (!value.StartsWith("@"))
                {
                    Data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
                }
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Now at this point I have modified the values of all items in the collection, and I want to update the original file. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `new XmlTextReader()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Second of all, an XmlReader is a read-only, forward-only cursor. You can't go back to write out the modified nodes.

You should use LINQ to XML, or an XmlDocument to do this sort of work.

Comment: I'll try XmlDocument. I didn't think I would be able to make the same selection as with the XmlReader, but after looking on MSDN again I think it's possible.

Comment: Since you've got .NET 4.0, you should use LINQ to XML. It's quite a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you don't use XSLT for this? It seems like it would be the most appropriate technology for doing this.

Comment: Unless I don't understand XSLT correctly, it won't help me. I need to find and replace values in the original file. The file has strings that need to be localized, so I want to replace those strings with an assigned constant. For example, <Label ID="MyLabel" Caption="Hello"> becomes <Label ID="MyLabel" Caption="LANG_HELLO">.

Comment: That's fairly straightforward in XSLT. Though as mentioned below, if you don't want to use XSLT then using an XmlDocument would work better than XMLReader, which is forward only and read only.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to modify a XML file, I recommend you use XDocument, providing the file is small enough to be loaded into memory.
Otherwise use XmlReader for reading combined with XmlWriter for writing, or XSLT.